# Is there a way to create unauthorised community page?

Tags: community, lightning-community, community-builder, community-cloud

I want to develop a community page using community builder and lightning components. I would publish it. I then want this page to be accessed by any user who has access to this URL, and we would be distributing this URL through emails which would be sent , say, from Marketing cloud. So, the user should be able to access this community page from his mailbox as unauthorised page, i.e without having to log in to salesforce or SF community. Is this feasible and if yes, how can this be achieved.

Comment: Force.com Sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible from within the community builder. create a page and set its access to "Public" from within the builder and publish it
[image]

Comment: I could access the page without authentication, thanks for answering! However, I am not able to see my lightning component that I have added to this page through community builder.  Could you please explain possible reason for this?

Comment: It could be profile access issue. If the lightning component is accessing sObjects provide access to them in the community site guest profile

Comment: Need 1 more favour. I created a new 'Page Variation'  and set it to default. Then I published it, but this time it does not let access the sObject. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: I would ask you to post a separate question with screenshot of the error and can help you.

Comment: It's posted here : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/244292/page-variation-of-a-community-page-does-not-allow-access-to-sobject