# Page variation of a community page does not allow access to sObject

Tags: customer-community, lightning-community, community-builder

This is realted to a question asked earlier here :

[Is there a way to create unauthorised community page?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/241768/is-there-a-way-to-create-unauthorised-community-page/241771?noredirect=1#comment370969_241771)

As per answer of this question, I could access the sObject and perform DML from an unauthorised published community page. Now I have created a page variation of same, made it default and then published it. But this time I am not able to access the sObject. The guest profile for that community still has all the access to this sObject. Is there any specific setting for this?

[image]

> More details about the question:

sObject referred here is a custom object, that is accessed through a lightning component, that was drag-dropped into page template. No apex controller is directly used. The lightning component is a simple form that shows 4 editable fields for this custom sObject via `force:recordData`
The profile(guest user profile) for this community page has all accesses(Read, write view, modify etc) related to this custom object.

Comment: Just by looking at this, its not clear what is your exact issue here. You will need to provide at least 3 things here for anyone to be able to help you. **1** The object you are referring to in this page. **2** How is the object being referenced in this page, viz., standard component, custom lightning component. If custom, then additional details about any Apex involved **3** Profile permissions for the object for Guest User profile

Comment: @JayantDas : Modified question and added more details. Please let me know if those are fine.

Comment: Profile access doesn’t extend to record access unless the profile has view all/modify all permissions. The reason here could be that the records are not shared with the Guest User. That’s what you should verify.